# Use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+ac+bc $ for all positive $a,b,c$.

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+ac+bc $ for all positive $a,b,c$.

That's what I've tried:

Let a Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality be :

\begin{array}
(((\sqrt{a} )^2+(\sqrt{b})^2+(\sqrt{c})^2 )\left(\left(\cfrac{ab}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2 +\left(\cfrac{ac} {\sqrt{b}}\right)^2+\left(\cfrac{bc}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^2\right)& \ge (ab+ac+bc)^2 \\
(a+b+c)(ab^2+\cfrac{a^2 c^2}{b}+b^2 c) &\ge (ab+ac+bc)^2 \\
\end{array}

However how should I now factorize the left hand side of the inequality as $(a^2+b^2+c^2) \cdot Something $ ?

I think I've made the problem harder than it needs to be .

Comment: Why Cauchy-Schwarz? It is easier just to invoke $ab\leq \frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)$ and so on for all products and add.

Comment: I see ,but it's just what my problem is asking as the author  has previously proved the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By C-S $\sum\limits_{cyc}(1+1)(a^2+b^2)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)^2$
and we are done!

Comment: I am quite a beginner,if you would expain your notation I would appreciate more you answer ...

Comment: Of course! By C-S $(1+1)(a^2+b^2)\geq(a+b)^2$. Hence, $(1+1)(a^2+b^2)+(1+1)(b^2+c^2)+(1+1)(c^2+a^2)\geq(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+a)^2$, which gives your inequality.

Comment: Also we can use C-S in the following form $(1+1+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(a+b+c)^2$, which gives your inequality again.

Comment: @Mr. Y, the first C-S gives $4(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+ac+bc)$; The second C-S gives $3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$, which gives your inequality again.

Comment: Yes sorry I've deleted my comment as I've figured it out few seconds later,my bad.Thanks for your help,I am grateful. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you insist on C-S, let
$$
u=(a,b,c),\quad v=(b,c,a).
$$
Then,
$$
\text{RHS}=u\cdot v\underbrace{\leq}_{\text{C-S}}||u||\times||v||=\text{LHS}.
$$

Comment: are $u$ and $v$ vectors ?$\vec{u}=(a,b,c) $ ?What is that cross sign ?

Comment: Yes, $u$ and $v$ are vectors. $\times$ is just multiplication (between scalars).

Comment: I've got $\left(a^2+b^2+c^2 \right)^2 \ge ab+bc+ac $. How do I turn this in the requested inequality ? (bear with me)

Comment: @Mr.Y $||u||=||v||=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$.

Comment: @ Kim Jong Un: You are good!

Answer (score -1):

[image][I have given a detailed proof using an easier method. Please click on this link to see the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBixg.png)