# Proving a seemingly simple inequality is proving difficult

Tags: inequality, formal-proofs

After what feels like an embarrassing hour of scribbling I can't seem to find a direct solution to the following problem

$Show \space that: a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca \space \space  \forall [a,b,c] \in Z^{+}_0 $

I've tried placing each integer in an arbitrary order like so:

$a\leq b \therefore ab \leq b^2$

$b \leq c \therefore bc \leq c^2 \implies$

$a \leq c \therefore$ *$ac \leq c^2$*

Naturally I tried to add up the inequalities but this clearly yielded no results, but by nature of the third inequality I run into issues; what have I missed?

**EDIT**

I've constructed newer perhaps more insightful inequalities from one of the Dr's answer below:

$a-b \leq ab \leq b^2$

$b-c \leq bc \leq c^2$

$a-c \leq ac \leq c^2$

**EDIT 2**

While I've seen this flagged as a possible duplicate, this question appears towards the beginning of an intro book to mathematical proofs without any prior knowledge given, I feel aso though this should be provable using pure inequalities from first principals

Comment: Apply AM/GM to $a^2$ and $b^2$, and then to the other couple of similar pairs.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown AM/GM?

Comment: Arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality

Comment: a possible duplicate or a real one?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1601949/42969.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033333/42969

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I don't see your "vote to close as a duplicate" yet. This has been asked and answered many times (including the same answers as below).

Comment: @MartinR please refer to my second edit

Comment: @Adrian: Have you checked the referenced Q&As? There are answers which require no prior knowledge, such as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64870/42969.

Comment: @Adrian, it is a duplicate question, of many questions.  Your edit doesn't change that.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: this is equivalent to $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.
this is also true for all real numbers $a,b,c$

Comment: On second thought I've not found the answer

Comment: nice, send them to me or to this Forum for the other solvers

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(2a^2-2ab)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a^2-2ab+b^2)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: While I'm inclined to accept Dr Sonnhard's answer, I'm curious as to what this is; can you please expand on this

Comment: @Adrian Yes of course. What is your question?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Firstly what are the sums referring to?

Comment: **Duplicate answer** See this same answer by the same user as we find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2171364)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  The right thing to have done here was to have identified the question as a duplicate.  To answer a duplicate question you've already answered, with the identically same answer you posted on the original, simply indicates that you will do anything, even break site rules or consensus, to gain points.

Comment: Not to mention that even the original is basically the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Adrian It's a cyclic sum. For example, for three variables we obtain: $\sum\limits_{cyc}a=a+b+c$; $\sum\limits_{cyc}ab=ab+bc+ca$; $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=a^2-ab+b^2-bc+c^2-ca$. Good luck!